# Xaml on WinPhone 8.1 working but shown as error by the IDE

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 is giving me someproblem during the WinPhone 8.1 development, the editor shows me errors that in fact aren't and the intellisense is not working as well.

I can even continue programming as it's compiling and running but it's really really annoying, can anyone help me on find this problem out?

PS: I already tried to repair visual studio 2013 and Windows Phone 8.1 SDK both!

UPDATE: If I add a name to an item like the button, I'm not able to retrieve it in the code behind!

[image: The screen of my the problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your ShadowCache. It is located in your user profile directory:

`app data\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache`

Comment: Just showing all the tags in red like they aren't correct and the intellisense does not work as well! You can see the attached image